# Power diagram algorithm

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry, pseudocode, voronoi

I have been trying to find a good description of an algorithm to create a 2D [power diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram), but so far turned up empty. Can anyone point me to either a Java implementation, or an (understandable) version in Scala or Python or pseudocode that I could base an implementation off?

My goal is using this within a Java application, so bundling native libraries would not be practical.

A O(n log(n)) algorithm would be great, but O(n^2) is probably sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found what I was looking for here: https://github.com/ArlindNocaj/power-voronoi-diagram

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid by some compilation, the C++ [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) implementation is available in python and java through the [cgal-bindings](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/) project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but for my application (in Java) I can't really bundle any native code.